# I'm trying to program a "latched button" for a robot, however when I run through the code the robot does not respond

Tags: java, button, robotics

I need to program a robot to drive at 50% speed when the 'a' button on a game controller is pressed and released, and then to drive at 100% when 'a' is pressed and released again, like a latched button.  I have the following code that makes the robot drive a 50% when 'a' is held down constantly, and at 100% when 'a' is released, it works fine.

```
    telemetry.addData("Status", "Running: " + runtime.toString());
    if(gamepad1.a)
    {
        telemetry.addData("Status", "A pressed");
                leftMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.left_stick_y*0.5);
                rightMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.right_stick_y*0.5);
                telemetry.addData("Status", "Running Slow");
            }

            else {
                leftMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.left_stick_y);
                rightMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.right_stick_y);
                telemetry.addData("Status", "Running regular");
                                }



}
```

And this is the code I have for the latched button, it does not drive when running. I think it is just a matter of fixing the if and else statements, but I cant pinpoint the problem .

```
    telemetry.addData("Status", "Running: " + runtime.toString());
    if(gamepad1.a)
    {
        telemetry.addData("Status", "A pressed");
        //if A was pressed
        if(aPressed == false)
        {
            aPressed = true;
            if(goingSlow)
            {
                leftMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.left_stick_y);
                rightMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.right_stick_y);
                telemetry.addData("Status", "Running Regular");
                goingSlow = false;
            }

                  else {
                    leftMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.left_stick_y*0.5);
                    rightMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.right_stick_y*0.5);
                    telemetry.addData("Status", "Running Slow");
                    goingSlow = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            aPressed = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to do too much inside the branches of the "if" statement. Moving some of the functionality to other methods should make things easier to understand.

It's difficult to know exactly what's going on, since you don't show the entire method, or provide any context about how you are notified of the button presses / releases, but you might want to try something like this, once you've dealt with the button presses and figured out whether you should be going slow or fast:

```
if(shouldGoFast) {
 goFast();
} else {
 goSlow();
}

public void goFast() {
  leftMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.left_stick_y);
  rightMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.right_stick_y);
  telemetry.addData("Status", "Running Regular"); 
}

public void goSlow() {
  leftMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.left_stick_y*0.5);
  rightMotor.setPower(-gamepad1.right_stick_y*0.5);
  telemetry.addData("Status", "Running Slow");
}
```

I'm assuming that you don't really need to keep track of whether you're currently going slow or fast, i.e. there's no problem if you execute goFast() when you're already going fast.